# How to extract IP address from the log's string with regular expression and Notepad++

Tags: networking, notepad++, regex

I've such kind of strings from the log file

```
rule family="ipv4" source address="54.246.81.158" reject
rule family="ipv4" source address="175.36.129.24" reject
```

How can I match an IP address from every of that string and then replace the original one with matched IP using regular expression in Notepad++ text editor?

**Expected result**:

```
54.246.81.158
175.36.129.24
```

I prefer to achieve the goal usig regexp and *Search and replace* only.
If it ever possible in Notepad++
I know that I can use macro functionality, but I don't want to do so.

So, at first, we'll match IP with regexp (`\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}`). At second we replace original string with IP from step #1
But I'm not sure if it ever possible using Notepad++. 
If I'm failed with this, I'll use vim :-)

Comment: If text `rule family="ipv4" source address="` is common in all lines, you can also replace your IP by recording a `macro` for one row and executing it till end of file.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve, please, edit your question and add more lines and expected result.

Comment: @Toto, Example added, done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?((?:\d+\.){3}\d+).+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
.+?         : 1 or more any character but newline
(           : start group 1
  (?:       : start non capture group
    \d+     : 1 or more digit
    \.      : a dot
  ){3}      : end group, must appear 3 times
  \d+       : 1 or more digit
)           : end group 1
.+          : 1 or more any character but newline
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (ie. the IP)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
54.246.81.158
175.36.129.24
```

To be sure you have an IP address, use

```
((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)))
```

instead of

```
((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)
```

Comment: That's what I want.

Thanks!

I used a very similar to your regexp, 
but my mistake 
was checked _matched newline_ box

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution, but not using RegEx:

Replace

```
rule family="ipv4" source address="
```

with nothing, and

```
" reject
```

with nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is _trick but not truth approach_ , IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the marked text as in the screenshot below.
Note that the regular expression should escape the dot.

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Otherwise, it will match non-IP number like this 12a34a56a78.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full Regular expression for matching IP addresses, that validates the following rules for valid IPv4 IP addresses.

1. Four integers ranging from zero to 255.
2. Any address with more than three dots (.) is not valid.
3. Any address with a number greater than 255 is invalid.

**REGEX**

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Let's break this into smaller pieces:

- [0-9][0-9]?   covers 0-99 numbers
- 1[0-9][0-9]   covers 100-199 numbers
- 2[0-9][0-9] - Should this be a valid IP address? **No**.
- 2[0-9][5]   - Should this be a valid IP address?  **No**.
- 2[0-4][0-9] - covers 200 to 249
- 25[0-5] - covers 250-255

If you would like to learn **how I build this REGEX step by step, you can check out this video** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGd5llvr7e4)

Here is a **quick demo** of several IP addresses validation.

[image: ip address validation regex]

*Disclaimer: This video is from my Youtube channel. But it goes into great details about how to validate IP addresses using REGEX. If there are many negative votes, I will remove the link. Thank you.*